# Does Flink Python API support gauge metric?

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I'm using PyFlink for streaming processing, and have added some metrics to monitor the performance.

Here's my code for registering the udf with metrics. I've installed apache-flink 1.13.0.

```
class Test(ScalarFunction):
    def __init__(self):
        self.gauge_value = 0

    def open(self, function_context):
        metric_group = function_context.get_metric_group().add_group("test")
        metric_group.gauge("gauge", lambda: self.gauge_value)

    def eval(self, i):
        self.gauge_value = i
        return i


test = udf(
    Test(),
    input_types=[DataTypes.BIGINT()],
    result_type=DataTypes.BIGINT(),
)
```

There's no exception raised from the log, and once I change the type of `self.gauge_value` to str, it'll go wrong, so I believe the line is executed and gauge is registered.

However, I could never find the gauge in the metrics tab of Web UI.
I tried to add counters and meters in this test udf, and they all showed up correctly in the metrics tab.

Is gauge supported in PyFlink? If not, is there any alternative of that?